# how to add more space to partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I try to use GParted to add more space to "/" directory. I can reduce the size of "linux-swap" but other partitions not changed. for example "/" partition the highest and the smallest size is one:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. how to reduce the size of "/home" and add to "/"?
2. What size partitions should they have?

[image]

Comment: Run `lsblk -a` and edit your question by adding the output of that command.

Comment: You haven't given much detail; some releases can use swapfiles thus no swap is required (we don't know your release).  The recommended minimum space is 25GB, though lots of blogs use less as it'll depend how & what software you want to add (more software requires more space), whether you'll *release-upgrade* (requires lots more space to download updates, then install them ie. old+downloaded+new before old is deleted) or you'll nuke & re-install clean come *release-upgrade* time as many bloggers suggest https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Well, all our _supported_ Ubuntu releases can use swap files; it's just that the kernel shipped with 16.04LTS has poor performance with swapping to a swap file when compared to swapping to a swap partition. That was fixed in fall of 2017 and versions 18.04 and 19.10 work just as well with a swap file, with one exception: Hibernation, If you use Hibernation in Ubuntu, a swap partition is still a good idea. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq has more.

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-lsblk-command/ and https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lsblk.8.html provide more on the _lsblk_ command.